# How to run C code from terminal?

Tags: c

I am working on an assignment for class, and we are to work off of a class server where the code files are held.

I have copied the files to my home directory, and have been editing with vim (since my instructor for some reason prefers it to emacs).

But how do I actually test my code? the make file is provided, and when I type `make test.c`, I get back `make: Nothing to be done for test.c`. I don't understand why this is happening, because I have a print statement as the first line in `main`. Shouldn't that at least run? Also, how do I pass arguments to the `main` function `test.c` while using `make`??

As a side question, this server doesn't have `gdb` either, for some reason. I'm sure there is an alternative installed, I just don't know what it would be called to try and see if it's here.

Comment: Have you actually read the makefile yet? Do you understand how to invoke executables?

Comment: Do you know what "compilation" means?

Comment: `make` *probably* just compiles your program – rather than both compiling and running it – and you’re not using it properly, either. Look inside the `Makefile` for a list of targets (they’re at the start of their respective lines in the form `target-name:`). `make test` might be correct. Then you can run your program and pass arguments as usual, e.g. `./test some args`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, I don't even know what a make file is. This is my first assignment in the class and it has been extremely vague. I have a lot of experience with Python, Java, and MATLAB, but I use IDE's for all of those and don't have low-level language experience.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara I see. in my case, `make` does compile and run it. My instructor specifically told us to use the `make` file to make sure our code works. I did as you suggested and just dropped the `.c` and it works (`make test`)

Comment: First thing: you have to learn how to use make (`man make` is a good start). You can get a list of the directives contained in your makefile (one word) by pressing TAB after `make ` (make followed by space). I **guess** that `make` without arguments will compile you prog and something like `make test` will run some tests. But everything depends on your Makefile. P.S. Are you really looking for `gdb` ? It is a debugger and is normally considered much more complex than `make`...

Comment: @mauro thanks for the info, I will use the `man` command. And yes, I did mean `gdb`. The assignment is to modify some existing code and a debugger would be very helpful. I have used `gdb` before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `make` is usually the thing you want it to create. Since `test.c` already exists, `make test.c` doesn't do anything. `make test` should compile `test.c` to create `test`. `make` with no arguments uses a default target specified in the `Makefile`; in your case it's probably the same as `make test`.

The `make` command doesn't *run* your program; it creates an executable that you can then run.

Once you've typed `make` or `make test`, you should be able to execute your program by typing

```
./test
```

The `./` is important; without it, you'll probably invoke the shell's built-in `test` command, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what u need is only this build command:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

Then:

```
./test
```

Have a try. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some basic knowledge in `make`. You should read some basic books on `makefile` and actually try it out. If you just try to stick concepts to your mind, but never actually try it out, you will never get it.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176427/comprehensive-gnu-make-gcc-tutorial) question. It asks for good tutorials on `GNU Make`. Also, so that you can go directly to the links, [this](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp) and [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) are links mentioned in the main answers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply save your code and then open the command prompt and write these command

1. gcc .\fileName.c and press Enter
2. Simply press a + tab and then print Enter and there you go.